# For which values of complex nb. c non-zero & |c|<1 has injective operator D-c.Id(H) of H (=l2) bounded inverse D=shift right Id=identity

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, operator-theory

Let H be the Hilbert space $\ell^2$ of all infinite sequences $(x_0,\dots,x_n,\dots)$ of complex numbers $x_n$ such that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |x_n|^2 < \infty$. Let D:H->H be the (continuous linear) right shift: D$(x_0,\dots,x_n,\dots) = (0, x_0,\dots,x_n,\dots)$, and for any complex c: $D_c$ = D - c.I where I is the identity map of H. I know that the residual spectrum $S_r$ of D consists of the open disk with radius 1 centered in 0 i.e. $S_r$ = {c complex | |c|<1}. Question: for which c in $S_r$ is the inverse of $D_c$ (defined on the range M of $D_c$) continuous? Or, equivalently, for which c in $S_r$ is M closed in H? I'm also looking for a proof of the answer. I exclude c=0 because that case is trivial (answer is yes, continuous / range closed)

Comment: May-be people get ideas for trying to answer, if I tell what I did myself (before posting) ... geometric progressions are important in the spectral analysis of left & right shifts so I tried y = (1,m,m^2, ... , m^n, ...) where parameter m was to be found s.t. || D_c (y) || <= eps.|| y || where eps>0 is arbitrary (c in resid. spectrum is fixed & m may depend on eps) ... this would make the inverse of D_c unbounded. I calculated that for this |c| must be 1 ... There might still be c's with unbounded inverse of D_c & IF SO something else than geom. seq. might serve. Proposals for this?

Comment: As you see in my first remark above, I tried to prove D_c unbounded i.e. not continuous. This is also because I am looking for an example where the c (like in T_c = T-c.I) is in the residual spectrum of T and T_c is unbounded (T linear bounded). But I finally tried to go for a bounded inverse for D_c and found yes, that is the answer for all c in the res. spectrum of D ... after finding new ideas and some tricks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to prove a converse of what makes any c such that |c|<1 a residual spectral value of shift operator D, namely that there is a non-zero element w of $\ell^2$ orthogonal to the range M of $D_c$ (so that M is not dense in $\ell^2$) - in fact one can take w = $(\bar c^n)_{n \scriptstyle \in \mathbb{N}}$ where the bar stands for complex conjugation ... as one can prove for example by using the adjoint of D (the left shift) for which c is an eigenvalue. If I prove that every element x of $\ell^2$ orthogonal to that special element w belongs to M, that will imply that M is the whole orthogonal subspace to {w} which is closed in $\ell^2$ ... from which follows (as mentioned in my original question) that $D_c$ has a continuous inverse ... because a continuous linear bijection from a Banach space to another is bicontinuous (by the open mapping theorem).

It goes like this. By hyp. x = $(x_n)_{n \scriptstyle \in \mathbb{N}}$ is orthogonal to w, i.e. the scalar product (x|w) = 0, thus $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n.c^n = 0$. Now - as indicated above - our purpose is to prove that x belongs to M, i.e. to find an element y of $\ell^2$ such that $D_c$(y) = x. This equation may be used to find the coordinates of y = $(y_n)_{n \scriptstyle \in \mathbb{N}}$ in case it exists; because $D_c$ is injective, there is only one possibility, and y will belong to $\ell^2$ if and only if the solution obtained makes the sum of all $|y_n|^2$ finite. By calculating, one finds the following result easily confirmed using proof by induction on the index: $y_n = - (\sum_{k=0}^n {x_k.c^k}) / c^{n+1}$. But we know that the sum of the $x_k.c^k$ for *all* k is zero, therefore we may write in our case that *(first trick)*: $\sum_{k=0}^n x_k.c^k  = - \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty x_k.c^k$; in taking the inverse of the denominator $c^{n+1}$ into the sum, we get (the two minus signs cancel): $y_n = \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty x_k.c^{k-n-1} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty x_{k+n+1}c^k$, this last equality resulting by shifting the indices in the terms of the sum. Now *(second trick)* let d,e be two complex numbers such that c=d.e and |d|<1,|e|<1 *e.g.* d=e=one of the square roots of c. We'll write the general term in the last infinite sum as $(x_{k+n+1}.d^k).e^k$. Now we apply Cauchy-Schwarz and get: $|y_n|^2 \le (\sum_{k=0}^\infty |x_{k+n+1}.d^k|^2) . (\sum_{k=0}^\infty |e^k|^2)$. Here the second factor doesn't depend on $n$. By adding for all n=0 to $\infty$, one can see that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |y_n|^2$ is finite. For details, see my comment *Details* below

Comment: *Details* The last part of the proof above needs to be completed. (I had forgotten first to reproduce a *third trick* (!) that I used in my proof drafts.) It goes like this: We have

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty|x_{k+n+1}d^{k}|^{2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{l=n+1}^\infty|x_{l}d^{l-1-n}|^{2} = \sum_{l=1}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^{l-1}|x_{l}d^{l-1-n}|^{2} = \sum_{l=1}^\infty\left(|x_l|^{2}\sum_{n=0}^{l-1}|d^{l-1-n}|^{2}\right)$$
and
$$\sum_{n=0}^{l-1}|d^{l-1-n}|^{2} = \sum_{n=0}^{l-1}|d^{n}|^{2} \le \sum_{n=0}^\infty|d^{n}|^{2}$$ therefore \sum_{n=0}^\infty|y^{n}|^{2} is indeed finite.

Comment: Could someone verify my proof?